# Git - roll back all local changes after messing up

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I can't find any relative answer for my problem. I have two branches at the moment:

- `master`
- `develop`

After commited and and pushed to server all modifications (to `develop` branch) I wanted to update `master` branch with a `develop` branch. Accidentally I've messed up, after mergin `master` with `develop` - a `master` now have everything from both branches, and that's not what I want to.

How do I restore everything on my local repo ? I've tried `git reset --hard HEAD` but it does not seem to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can reset your branch to the state it was in just before the merge if you find the commit it was on then.

Use `git reflog`, it will list all the HEADs you've had.
I find that `git reflog --relative-date` is very useful as it shows how long ago each change happend.

Once you find that commit just do a `git reset --hard <commit id>` and your branch will be as it was before.

---

**Solution 2:**

you can simply `git revert` the merge commit like so:

```
git checkout BRANCH_NAME
git revert -m 1 <merge_commit_sha>
```

**Note :** It is possible that you will end up with some conflicts that you'll have to manually unmerge, just like when merging normally.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to checkout specific commit:

```
git checkout [revision-hash] .
```

Pass hash of the commit from before the merge

Comment: it doesn't help unfortunately...  I've messed up somehow a `develop` branch now... isn't there something like to ignore everything and restore to specific version without leaving actual files inplace ?

Comment: only removing the whole local project and cloning it back from remote git worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

With the master branch currently checked out:

```
git reset --hard develop
```

will switch to develop branch losing all changes from master except those which have already been included in develop branch.